# Как в ListView вывести определенные пункты, а не все данные. Как добавить в избранное?

Tags: android, listview

Здравствуйте. Я все пытаюсь реализовать добавление в избранное.
Что у меня на данный момент есть. Список ListView который загружает данные из ресурса string.xml. Обработчик нажатия - при нажатии на пункт списка открывается второе Активити с полным текстом.

Также во втором Активити есть кнопка, при нажатии на которую сохраняется с помощью SharedPreferences, номер позиции ListView.

В первом Активити сверху есть кнопка избранное при нажатии на которую будут оставаться в активити только те пункты которые добавил в избранное.

Так вот я нажал на заголовок списка, открылось второе активити, далее нажимаю на кнопку, сохраняется номер позиции, возвращаюсь в первое активити, теперь нажимаю на кнопку избранное получаю из SharedPreferences, номер позиции.

Вопрос как теперь отфильтровать ListView, что бы в списки были только те пункты которые были сохранены в SharedPreferences?

Ну и второй вопрос как в SharedPreferences, сохранять несколько пунктов, при нажатии на кнопку.

Не знаю правильной ли я вообще пошел дорогой, может это как-то по другому можно было реализовать.

Код первого активити со списком

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView listView;

// переменная, представляющая экземпляр класса SharedPreferences
SharedPreferences mSettings;

// это будет именем файла настроек
public static final String APP_PREFERENCES = "mysettings";
// имя кота
public static final String APP_PREFERENCES_NAME = "Nickname";

TextView tvInfo;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    // получаем экземпляр элемента ListView
    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

    // инициализирем эту переменную
    // в скобках - название вашего файла и стандартное разрешение
    mSettings = getSharedPreferences(APP_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    tvInfo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvInfo);

    // определяем массив типа String
    // заголовок
    final String[] catnames = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cat_names);

    // два списка которые откроются во втором активити

    final String[] catnames2 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cat_names2);
    final String[] catnames3 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cat_names3);

    // используем адаптер данных
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.item, catnames);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    // массив количество элементов
    final int[] mice = new int [catnames.length];

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View itemClicked, int position,long id) {
            TextView textView = (TextView) itemClicked;
            // получаем текст нажатого элемента
            String strText = textView.getText().toString();

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LastActivity.class);

            // получаем пункт нажатого элемента
            int intText = position;
            String str = Integer.toString(intText);
            intent.putExtra("punkt", str);

            for(int x=0;x<catnames.length;x++){
                mice[x]=x; // заполняем массив
                System.out.println(mice[x]); // выводим массив в цикле
                if (strText == catnames[x]) {
                    // Запускаем активность, связанную с определенным именем кота
                    // для отправки в другой класс. Ключ и значение(то что в поле editText)
                    intent.putExtra("name1", catnames[x]);
                    intent.putExtra("name2", catnames2[x]);
                    intent.putExtra("name3", catnames3[x]);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    //searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(textChangeListener);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

// кнопка избранное
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_favorite) {
        if(mSettings.contains(APP_PREFERENCES_NAME)) {
            // выводим данные в TextView
            tvInfo.setText(mSettings.getString(APP_PREFERENCES_NAME, ""));
        }
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Второе активити с полным текстом и с кнопкой добавить в избранное

```
public class LastActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView textView;
TextView textView2;
TextView textView3;
TextView textView4;

String name1;
String name2;
String name3;
String name4;

// переменная, представляющая экземпляр класса SharedPreferences
SharedPreferences mSettings;
// это будет именем файла настроек
public static final String APP_PREFERENCES = "mysettings";
// имя кота
public static final String APP_PREFERENCES_NAME = "Nickname";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_last);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    // инициализирем эту переменную
    // в скобках - название вашего файла и стандартное разрешение
    mSettings = getSharedPreferences(APP_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    // находим в коде
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    textView4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.punkt);

    // получаем Intent извликаем из него объект
    Intent intent = getIntent();

    // извлекаем из него объект
    name1 = intent.getStringExtra("name1");
    name2 = intent.getStringExtra("name2");
    name3 = intent.getStringExtra("name3");
    name4 = intent.getStringExtra("punkt");

    // выводим полученные данные
    textView.setText(name1);
    textView2.setText(name2);
    textView3.setText(name3);

    // кнопка добавить в избранное
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(LastActivity.this, getString(R.string.action_favorite), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // SharedPreferences.Editor - редактировать
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSettings.edit();
            // сохраняем его через метод putString() (есть также putLong(), putBoolean() и т.п.)
            editor.putString(APP_PREFERENCES_NAME, name4);
            // commit() или apply() чтобы изменение вступила в силу
            editor.apply();
        }
    });
}
```

}
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Для такой функциональности оптимальным решением будет использование базы данных, которая позволяет делать выборки по условию и предоставляет готовые данные, соответствующие условию, наиболее быстро и оптимально.

Создаете таблицу следующей структуры:

|  _id | name | advanced | favorite |

в поле *name* заносите имена своих котов, поле *advanced* будет содержать дополнительные сведения (таких полей может быть несколько), поле *favorite* будет индикатором отметки избранного, в это поле будет записываться определенный признак (например: true) при добавлении этого кота в избранное. Теперь всего два запроса решат вашу проблему легко и правильно.

1. Выборка всей таблицы по полю *name* для отображения полного списка имен
2. Выборка по условию: favorite = true, сформирует список избранного
3. При клике в списке имен, вы получите ID записи, по которому сможете сделать выборку дополнительных сведений в другом активити

Теперь остается только отправить полученную из БД выборку в адаптер для отображения или заполнить виджеты дополнительными сведениями в активити

Стоит заметить, что `SharedPreferences` вовсе не предназначены для хранения такого рода данных и использование их в таких целях крайне не оправдано.

Насчет самой БД от себя рекомендовал бы сразу начать изучать ORM [Realm](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/), как наиболее качественный и удобный продукт в данной области, НО! если есть свободное время и нервы, можно потратить его на стандартные классы Android для работы с SQL (`SQLiteOpenHelper`, `Cursor`, `CursorLoader` и др.), учитывая, что это заранее более трудозатратный и мозговыносящий вариант.

Варианты различных манипуляций со списками (коллекциями) будут заведомо костыльными для такого рода задачи.

**UPD**

По работе с ORM Realm нет каких-то особых исключений, она создана по "правилам" работы СУБД вообще и ORM в частности, то есть общих знаний по работе с базами данных вполне достаточно для ее полномерного использования.
Начальные сведения (которых уже хватит для решения вашей задачи) [доступно изложены](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/) в кратком руководстве на ресурсе проекта. Здесь есть все основные моменты: поддерживаемые типы данных, создание объекта-модели (RealmObject), запись в БД (CommitTransaction), установление отношений один ко многим и многие ко многим (Relationships), изменение записей, чтение и составление запросов (Queries), работа с результатами запроса (RealmResults) и тд. , кроме того есть [готовые сэмплы](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#examples), где можно посмотреть на использование "в живую".

Дополнительно в [новостях](https://realm.io/news/tags/android/) периодически появляется какая то информация, так же есть серия [видео-роликов с уроками](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=android+relm) по этой ORM. Есть даже какой-то научный [доклад на русском языке](http://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/kratkiy-obzor-mobilnoy-subd-realm-dlya-google-android)

Полный список доступных классов и методов [изложен в API](https://realm.io/docs/java/1.2.0/api/)

Для работы со списками (ListView и RecyclerView) в API Realm включены [классы-адаптеры](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#working-with-android) , там же есть инструкция по подключению в проект и сэмплы с примерами использования.

На SoF так же собрана уже достаточно [большая база знаний](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D%20%5Brealm%5D%20realm).

Всего этого вполне достаточно для работы, ключевым моментом здесь, видимо, является понимание работы с базами данных вообще и вот этому нужно научится перед тем, как их использовать, так как это достаточно сложная дисциплина

Comment: Коты это для примера)) приложение не об этом будет. Но спасибо буду разбираться с БД.

Comment: Информации я смотрю в интернете по ORM Realm очень мало, посоветуйте пожалуйста какой нибудь источник по Realm

Comment: @Artsait дополнил ответ немного

Comment: Пожалуйста ответь на один вопрос. Кровью и потом я создал таблицу, заполнил её данными _id | name | advanced | favorite. Все вроде стало работать.
И вдруг я понял что при генерации APK, БД туда не попадает. Подскажи хотя бы в двух словах, что мне теперь с этой таблицой делать? Можно ли её привезать к APK файлу

Comment: @Artsait А как вы заполняли БД и какую БД используете. Создайте вопрос с этой проблемой.

Answer (score 2):

Вообще хранить избранное по номеру позиции довольно сомнительное решение, так как при изменениях в ресурсах они могут поплыть.
Но если очень хочется то примерно так:

1. По нажатию на кнопку получается коллекция и список id элементов которые в избранном
2. По каждому id выдергивается элемент и сохраняется в новый список
3. Делаете новый адаптер и сеттите его \ или используете notifySetDataChanges

Как то так.

Comment: Да мне не хочется добавлять в избранное по позиции, я просто не знаю как можно это сделать. До того как стал писать это приложение был уверен, что в интернете готовых решений очень много, но пока ничего внятного и понятного не нашел