# Как импортировать библиотеку ORM Realm в Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, orm, библиотеки, realm

Не могу загрузить библиотеку `ORM Realm` в `Android Studio`. Обычно для загрузки сторонней библиотеки достаточно было прописать в `build.gradle` строку, в данном случае я попытался ввести:

```
dependencies {
compile 'io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:1.1.0'
}
```

Но при импорте в классе не видит `RealmObject`

```
import io.realm.RealmObject;

dependencies {
classpath 'io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:1.1.0'
}
```

То выдает ошибку:

> Error:(27, 0) Could not find method classpath() for arguments
>   [io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:1.1.0] on object of type
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
>       Open
>   File

Кто устанавливал Realm? Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На сайте проекта есть [подробная инструкция](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#installation):

1. В build.gradle [уровня проекта](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/examples/build.gradle) пишем

   ```
   buildscript {
     repositories {
         jcenter()
     }
     dependencies {
         classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:1.2.0"
     }
   ```

   }
2. В build.gradle [уровня приложения](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/examples/introExample/build.gradle) :

   ```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
   apply plugin: 'realm-android'
   ```
3. Обновляем конфигурацию Gradle (tools -> android -> sync project with gradle files)

Comment: Спасибо)) Вы не знаете случайно где есть полезная документация для новичков по Realm, хотя бы как добавить и загрузить из таблицы строку? 
Все что находил или для айфона или сам черт не разберет

Comment: @Artsait На том же сайте далее (ссылка на документацию в ответе) есть все основные CRUD операции для Java/Android. Еще [здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/559151/177345) я немного писал по информации о Realm

Comment: Точна я вспомнил. Будем разбираться

Answer (score 2):

Читай внимательно документацию:
[документация](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#getting-started), там есть еще одна вещь такая как:

> Step 2: Apply the realm-android plugin to the top of application level
>   build.gradle file.
>
> `apply plugin: 'realm-android'`

Comment: Спасибо. Не внимательно прочитал