# Посоветуйте как правильно реализовать корзину в приложений

Tags: java, android

Пишу  клиент (андроид)- серверное (php/mysql) приложение,есть таблица продуктов,на стороне клиента нужно реализовать добавление в избранные,подскажите в какую сторону копать?

Comment: Попробуйте более полно сформулировать вопрос. Добавить в избранное нужно локально или на сервере?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/559151/177345 ?

Comment: желательно добавить локально,через сервер знаю как реализовать

Answer (score 0):

Храните все в БД. Или же сделайте какой-нибудь синглетон в котором будете хранить данные в списке. Вопрос абстрактный, вариантов много