# Добавить в избранное как тут

Tags: android

В этом приложении как на скрине есть кнопка "Добавить в избранное" в кастомном ListView. Подскажите как такое можно реализовать? У меня реализован кастомный ListView, куда данные выводятся из БД. Есть колонка favorites в таблице БД. Примерно такой же кастомный ListView реализовал. Но не пойму как по нажатию на кнопку сделать избранным выбранный пункт

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/559151/177345

Comment: Может вы меня не так поняли. Меня интересовало как при нажатии на кнопку "в избранное" в пункте в БД заносить инфо. Т.е. где прописывать обработчик? В классе-адаптере? В классе MainActivity? БД и все остальное у меня сделано уже