# Как сделать избранное в списке ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно при нажатии на  определенный пункт из `ListView` добавить его в другой Активити, то есть говоря простым языком - добавить его в "Избранное"? с помощью каких методов можно сделать подобное?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/559151/177345

Comment: Из всего что там написано понял только что нужно создать базу данных, я начинающий

Comment: Из того, что написано в вашем вопросе, можно только посоветовать начинать изучать работу с базами данных. Как здесь [задавать вопросы](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), чтобы получить полезный ответ.

Answer (score -1):

`OnItemClickListener` просто в нем открыт новый `intent` и передавать в него данные

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы

Comment: То есть через Intent можно будет передавать данные из одного ListView в другой ListView?

Comment: А в каком из них нужно создавать OnItemClickListener?