# Как добавлять элементы в избранное из списка Recycler view? (Favorites)

Tags: android, listview, recyclerview, adapter, android-shared-preferences

Есть адаптер со списком элементов., которые загружаются из json, который собственно говоря находится внутри приложения.

Как добавлять элементы из ListView в избранное?

Код класса **Favorites.class:**

```
public class Favorites {

private static List<String> favoriteUrls = null;

private static File getFavoritesPath() {
    return new File(CacheManager.getRoot(), "favorites");
}

public static void load() {
    Sack.open(String[].class, getFavoritesPath()).load(new Sack.Listener<String[]>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(final Sack.Status status, final String[] favorites) {
            favoriteUrls = new ArrayList<String>();
            if (favorites == null)
                return;
            for (String favorite : favorites)
                favoriteUrls.add(favorite);
        }
    });
}

public static List<Station> getFavorites() {
    final List<Station> favorites = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String url : favoriteUrls)
        favorites.add(Directory.getStation(url));

    Station.sort(favorites);
    return favorites;
}

public static void addFavorite(final String favoriteUrl) {
    if (!favoriteUrls.contains(favoriteUrl)) {
        favoriteUrls.add(favoriteUrl);
        commit();
    }
}

public static void removeFavorite(final String favoriteUrl) {
    if (favoriteUrls.contains(favoriteUrl)) {
        favoriteUrls.remove(favoriteUrl);
        commit();
    }
}

private static void commit() {
    final String[] urls = favoriteUrls.toArray(new String[favoriteUrls.size()]);
    Sack.open(String[].class, getFavoritesPath()).commit(urls);
}

public static void addFavorite(Station serializableExtra) {
}
```

}

Не совсем пойму как, что и куда нужно дописать, чтоб можно было сохранять элементы из listview*??

**код Адаптера:**

```
public class DirectoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DirectoryAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private static int MODE_DIRECTORY = 0;
private static int MODE_FAVORITES = 1;

public interface Listener {
    void onStationClicked(final Station station);
}

private final List<Station> stations = new LinkedList<>();
private Listener listener;
private int mode;

public DirectoryAdapter() {
    stations.addAll(getStations());
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {
    final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.directory_item, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final Station station = stations.get(position);
    holder.nameView.setText(station.getName());
    holder.descriptionView.setText(String.format("%s (%s)", station.getDescription(), station.getNetwork()));

    Picasso.with(holder.itemView.getContext()).load(station.getIconUrl()).fit().centerCrop().transform(new Transformation() {
        @Override
        public Bitmap transform(final Bitmap source) {
            PaletteCache.generate(station.getIconUrl(), source);
            return source;
        }

        @Override
        public String key() {
            return station.getIconUrl();
        }
    }).into(holder.iconView, new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            final Palette palette = PaletteCache.get(station.getIconUrl());
            if (palette == null)
                return;

            final Palette.Swatch swatch = palette.getVibrantSwatch();
            if (swatch != null) {
                holder.nameView.setTextColor(swatch.getRgb());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError() {

        }
    });

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {
            if (listener != null)
                listener.onStationClicked(station);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public long getItemId(final int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return stations.size();
}

private List<Station> getStations() {
    if (mode == MODE_FAVORITES) {
        return Favorites.getFavorites();
    }

    return Directory.getStations();
}

public void showFavorites() {
    mode = MODE_FAVORITES;
    updateStations();
}

public void showDirectory() {
    mode = MODE_DIRECTORY;
    updateStations();
}

public void setListener(final Listener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}


public void filterStations(final String query) {
    List<Station> filteredStations = queryStations(query);
    updateStations(filteredStations);
}

public void updateStations(final List<Station> filteredStations) {
    removeFilteredStations(filteredStations);
    addFilteredStations(filteredStations);
}

public void updateStations() {
    updateStations(getStations());
}

private void removeFilteredStations(final List<Station> filteredStations) {
    final Iterator<Station> iterator = stations.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        final Station station = iterator.next();
        if (!filteredStations.contains(station)) {
            final int position = stations.indexOf(station);
            iterator.remove();
            notifyItemRemoved(position);
        }
    }
}

private void addFilteredStations(final List<Station> filteredStations) {
    for (Station station : filteredStations) {
        if (!stations.contains(station)) {
            final int position = findPosition(station);
            stations.add(position, station);
            notifyItemInserted(position);

        }
    }
}

private int findPosition(final Station station) {

    int position = 0;
    while(position < stations.size() && stations.get(position).getName().compareToIgnoreCase(station.getName()) < 0) {
        position++;
    }

    return position;
}

private List<Station> queryStations(final String query) {
    final List<Station> filtered = new ArrayList<>();

    final boolean isEmpty = TextUtils.isEmpty(query);
    for (Station station : getStations()) {
        if (isEmpty || station.matchesQuery(query))
            filtered.add(station);
    }
    return filtered;
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView iconView;
    TextView nameView, descriptionView;

    public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        iconView = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        nameView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        descriptionView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
    }
}
```

}

Каким образом сохранять элементы, и потом получать этот список с избранным??

**главное активити:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, DirectoryAdapter.Listener, SearchView.OnQueryTextListener, PlayerView.Listener {

private static final String TAG = Log.buildTag(MainActivity.class);

private PlaybackService playbackService = null;
private RecyclerView directory;
private PlayerView playerView;
private DirectoryAdapter adapter;
private CoordinatorLayout container;
private SearchView searchView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    startService(new Intent(this, PlaybackService.class));

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    container = (CoordinatorLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);

    directory = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.directory);
    directory.setHasFixedSize(true);
    directory.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 3, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
    directory.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(final RecyclerView recyclerView, final int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING) {
                final InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

                if (imm.isAcceptingText()) {
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(directory.getWindowToken(), 0);
                }
            }
        }
    });

    adapter = new DirectoryAdapter();
    directory.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.setListener(this);

    playerView = (PlayerView)findViewById(R.id.player);
    playerView.setListener(this);

    onPlayerStateChanged(null);

    setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) playerView.getLayoutParams();
    final SwipeDismissBehavior<PlayerView> swipeDismissBehavior = new SwipeDismissBehavior<>();
    swipeDismissBehavior.setSwipeDirection(SwipeDismissBehavior.SWIPE_DIRECTION_START_TO_END);
    swipeDismissBehavior.setListener(new SwipeDismissBehavior.OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss(final View view) {
            stopPlayback();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDragStateChanged(final int i) {

        }
    });
    params.setBehavior(swipeDismissBehavior);

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    bindService(new Intent(this, PlaybackService.class), serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    unbindService(serviceConnection);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    final EventBus instance = EventBus.getInstance();
    instance.register(this);
    instance.register(playerView);

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    final EventBus instance = EventBus.getInstance();
    instance.unregister(this);
    instance.unregister(playerView);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (searchView.isIconified()) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    } else {
        searchView.setQuery(null, true);
        searchView.clearFocus();
        searchView.setIconified(true);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    final MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    final boolean rv;
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            rv = true;
            break;

        case R.id.action_favorites:
            showFavorites();
            rv = true;
            break;

        default:
            rv = super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            break;
    }

    return rv;
}

private void showFavorites() {
    adapter.showFavorites();
}

@Override
public void onClick(final View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.playback:
            togglePlayback();
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
    adapter.filterStations(query);
    directory.scrollToPosition(0);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onStationClicked(final Station station) {
    playerView.setTranslationX(0);
    playerView.setAlpha(1);

    if (playbackService != null)
        playbackService.loadStation(station);
}

@Subscribe
public void onPlayerStateChanged(final PlayerStateChange update) {
    final Streamer streamer = Streamer.getInstance();
    final boolean isPlaying = !streamer.isStopped();
    playerView.setVisibility(isPlaying ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
}

@Subscribe
public void onError(final PlayerError error) {
    Log.e(TAG, "player error", error.error);
    Toast.makeText(this, error.error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public void togglePlayback() {
    if (playbackService != null)
        playbackService.togglePlayback();
}

private void stopPlayback() {
    if (playbackService != null)
        playbackService.stopPlayback();
}

final ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(final ComponentName name, final IBinder service) {
        playbackService = ((PlaybackService.LocalBinder)service).getService();
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(final ComponentName name) {
        playbackService = null;
    }
};

@Override
public void openStation(final Station station) {
    final Intent intent = StationActivity.getInstance(this, Streamer.getInstance().getStation());
    startActivity(intent);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, 0);
}
```

}

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/559151/177345