# Выборка значений из одной таблицы по индексу другой таблицы

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Есть две таблицы в базе данных. Первая таблица содержит 3 колонки:

`|   ID   |   ItemTitle   |   ItemContent   |`

Вторая таблица 2 колонки:

`|   ID   |   Favorite   |`

Мне требуется отобразить данные первой таблицы по индексам `Favorite` второй таблицы, где `Favorite` является типом `NUMERIC`.

```
Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(MainItemTable.mainItemTable,
        MainItemTable.columnsMainItem,
        // тут нужно обратиться к индексу Favorite другой таблицы
        // например, пытался сделать так: FavoriteTable.favorite + " = 1",
        null, null, null, null);
```

Возможно ли такое? Я так полагаю, что даже если возможно мне нужно будет делать `rawQuery`?

Comment: можно и query и rawquery https://stackoverflow.com/a/34688420/9271527

Comment: какая связь между таблицами? по избранному [немного писал ранее](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/559151/177345), в общем то тут не нужны две таблицы, это только усложнит выборку

Comment: @pavlofff таблиц много, есть таблица с основным содержимым, есть таблица категорий, а категорий может быть очень много, со всех таблиц реализована возможность добавлять пункты в избранное, и я решил для индексов избранного использовать одну таблицу, более продуманного способа не нашел)) вот и возникла мысль делать выборку из другой таблицы.

Comment: @pavlofff в принципе еще была мысль, сделать таблицу favorite аналогичной основной таблице, и если пользователь добавляет в избранное, это пункт копируется в таблицу favorite, но пока что не стал так делать, так как каждый пункт еще можно редактироваться, и потом после редакта нужно будет обновлять его в текущем пункте и в таблице favorite

Comment: если в таблице избранного ID соответствует ID избранной записи в таблице контента,  то запрос будет вида: `SELECT ItemTitle, ItemContent FROM TableContent, TableFavorite WHERE TableFavorite.ID = TableContent.ID `. для расширения кругозора можно (и нужно) почитать про связи в SQL - один ко многим, многие ко многим. вторая мысль неправильная совсем :)

Comment: @pavlofff разобрался вроде) про почитать согласен)) всему свое время, пока что на очереди другие книги)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все оказалось куда нельзя проще:

```
Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Main_item_table, Favorite_table WHERE favorite = 1", null);
```

Comment: но так у вас нет никакой связи между таблицами, при удалении одних и затем добавлении других записей порядок будет нарушен и все "поплывет". sql-базы не гарантируют очередность элементов, должна быть явная связь, например по id, поэтому надо либо отложить другие книги и читать по sql (могу посоветовать "изучаем sql" Л.Бейли - очень доступно) , либо отложить эту задачу

Comment: @pavlofff Пожалуй отложу другие книги)